# why $\int_{0}^ {x} = \int_{\frac{-1}{2}}^{y}$ and $\int_{0}^{x} = \int_{y}^{1} ?$

Tags: calculus, integration

I have some confusion in integration . My confusion marked in red and green circle as given below[image]

Im not getting  why $$\int_{0}^ {x} = \int_{\frac{-1}{2}}^{y}$$ and $$\int_{0}^{x} = \int_{y}^{1} $$ ?

Im not getting  how its derive ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Try to plot these areas and look firstly from $Ox$, then from $Oy$ axes.

More formally: we should prove

$$\left\{ \begin{array}{} 
0 \leqslant x \leqslant 1 \\
0 \leqslant y \leqslant x 
\end{array} \right\} = \left\{ \begin{array}{}
0 \leqslant y \leqslant 1 \\
y \leqslant x \leqslant 1
\end{array} \right\}
$$
and then obtain
$$\int\limits_{0}^{1}\int\limits_{0}^{x} dxdy= \int\limits_{0}^{1}\int\limits_{y}^{1}dydx$$
Same for second.

Comment: thanks u @Zkutch  but little confusion  that first integration is  about negative i,e from $-1/2 $ to $y$ u have not included the negative

Comment: On interval $[0, -\frac{1}{2}]$ integral $\int_{0}^{x}$ is negative, because $y=x$ is less then $y=0$. Would you like me add formal representation to answer?

Answer (score 1):

In the integral in your problem, the bounds are $0<y<x$, so, as @zkutch wrote, if you plot the graph $y=f(x)=x$, the area will be the lower triangle if you split the unit square $([0,1]\times[0,1])$ with this function. The same area corresponds to the bounds $y<x<1$. Do the same with $[-\frac{1}{2},0]$ interval.

To verify that the integrals can be interchanged, Fubini-Tonelli's theorem must be verified:
$$
\int_{B}f = \int_{B}f^{+} + \int_{B}f^{-}
$$
Since your function is bounded on the compact set, both of these integrals are finite, so integrals can be interchanged.